# How to get all files and folders with metatdata from sharepoint folder whose threshold is crossed using rest api?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, threshold

I am fetching data from a folder inside sharepoint library.It has 7K files and folders.
I m using velow query.
"/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='" + ListName + "')?$select=ID,EncodedAbsUrl,File_x0020_Type&$expand=Folders,Folders/ListItemAllFields/HasUniqueRoleAssig

nments,Files/ModifiedBy/Title,Files/ListItemAllFields/HasUniqueRoleAssignments,Folders/ListItemAllFields,Files,Files/ListItemAllFields,Files/ListItemAllFields/FileSizeDisplay&$orderby=Modified desc";

It is giving threshold error.

I am trying by updating query to -

1. "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + ListName + "')?$select=ID,CustomID,EncodedAbsUrl,File_x0020_Type&$expand=Folders,Folders/ListItemAllFields/HasUniqueRoleAssignments,Files/ModifiedBy/Title,Files/ListItemAllFields/HasUniqueRoleAssignments,Folders/ListItemAllFields,Files,Files/ListItemAllFields,Files/ListItemAllFields/FileSizeDisplay&$filter=CustomID gt '8316' and CustomID lt '8318'&$orderby=CustomID desc";

where CustomID is indexed column.It is also giving same threshold crossed error.

2. "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='" + ListName + "')?$select=ID,EncodedAbsUrl,File_x0020_Type&$expand=Folders,Folders/ListItemAllFields/HasUniqueRoleAssignments,Files/ModifiedBy/Title,Files/ListItemAllFields/HasUniqueRoleAssignments,Folders/ListItemAllFields,Files,Files/ListItemAllFields,Files/ListItemAllFields/FileSizeDisplay&$top=5";

It is also throwing same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `$top` and `$skip` parameters in your API request and bring whole data in batches. Moreover, make sure the columns that you are using to filter the response are indexed.

Comment: $top is not working in case of GetFolderByServerRelativePath . Even if threshold is not crossed $top is giving all the content of folder by ignoring $top.